# i have a phrase which contains different parts, I need to split them using SQL, three is no delimeter in the phrase

Tags: mysql, sql

```
         Text      |
--------------------
ABC01BNMp02UIO09zxz01
```

there is a column say 'text' which contains values like ABC01BNMp02UIO09zxz01. I need to parse that out something like this ABC01 BNMp02 UIO09 zxz01 separately. I used "split_part" but didn't work.
any help would be appreciated.
Split_part(Text,'',4)

Comment: What database are you really using?  Don't use incompatible database tags.

Comment: i'm using mysql

Comment: ___something like___ Can you be Precise please. something like could be anything

Comment: If you have fixed width for each part, substring() is probably the way to go...

Comment: Why do you store the parts as one string in the database when you are actually interested in the separate parts? Make this separate columns and you won't have this problem any longer.

Comment: I have a column which contains values like following

Comment: DO you create this column by concatenating 4 seperate values before storing it on the database

Comment: In the manual there is a function called [SUBSTRING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) Join us in there

Comment: no, actually I am getting value like this 
klm1hl06desc01ash01   
klm1hl06desc02ash01
klm1hl06desc04ash01
klm1hl07desc01ash02
klm1hl02desc02ash02
each part indicates a general code

Comment: This is not proper relational design. There's no easy way to split a single string into a dynamic number of parts. You should normalize the design and put each code in a separate row.

Comment: This isn't really a job for sql.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following (in PHP):

```
<?php
$str = 'ABC01BNMp02UIO09zxz01';
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]+)/i',$str);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Outputs:

> Array ( [0] => ABC01 [1] => BNMp02 [2] => UIO09 [3] => zxz01 )